# Acessar banco de dados que está fora do ambiente docker

Tags: docker, microsserviços

Eu criei um ambiente de microserviços, mais precisamente 5 serviços, onde estão conectados entre si e acessam o mesmo banco de dados (PostgreSQL).
Após o desenvolvimento, eu comecei a criar as imagens docker para os serviços.
Todas as imagens foram criadas, porém, eu não posso colocar o postgreSQL no ambiente docker, pois ela já está rodando na máquina em localhost, e outras aplicações dependem dela, sendo assim, não posso migrar pro ambiente docker.
Eu gostaria de saber se é possível as minhas aplicações acessarem o banco de dados que está fora do ambiente?

Abaixo, meu docker-compose:

```
version: '2'
services:
    server:
        image: microservices/server:latest
        mem_limit: 1073741824 # RAM 1GB
        environment:
          - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
        expose:
          - "8080"
        ports:
          - "8080:8080"
        networks:
          - microservices
    security-server:
        image: microservices/security-server:latest
        mem_limit: 1073741824 # RAM 1GB
        environment:
          - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
        depends_on:
          - server
        expose:
          - "8081"
        ports:
          - "8081:8081"
        networks:
          - microservices
        restart: "always"
    api-gateway:
        image: microservices/api-gateway:latest
        mem_limit: 1073741824 # RAM 1GB
        environment:
          - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
        depends_on:
          - server
          - security-server          
        expose:
          - "9999"
        ports:
          - "9999:9999"
        networks:
          - microservices
        restart: "always"         
    imovel:
        image: microservices/imovel:latest
        mem_limit: 1073741824 # RAM 1GB
        environment:
          - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
        depends_on:
          - server
          - security-server
          - api-gateway        
        expose:
          - "8082"
        ports:
          - "8082:8082"
        networks:
          - microservices          
        restart: "always" 
    imovel2:
        image: microservices/imovel:latest
        mem_limit: 1073741824 # RAM 1GB
        environment:
          - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
        depends_on:
          - server
          - security-server
          - api-gateway         
        expose:
          - "9098"
        ports:
          - "9098:9098"
        networks:
          - microservices          
        restart: "always"
    imovel3:
        image: microservices/imovel:latest
        mem_limit: 1073741824 # RAM 1GB
        environment:
          - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
        depends_on:
          - server
          - security-server
          - api-gateway         
        expose:
          - "9097"
        ports:
          - "9097:9097"
        networks:
          - microservices          
        restart: "always"
    imovel3:
        image: microservices/imovel:latest
        mem_limit: 1073741824 # RAM 1GB
        environment:
          - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
        depends_on:
          - server
          - security-server
          - api-gateway         
        expose:
          - "9096"
        ports:
          - "9096:9096"
        networks:
          - microservices          
        restart: "always"
    imovel4:
        image: microservices/imovel:latest
        mem_limit: 1073741824 # RAM 1GB
        environment:
          - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
        depends_on:
          - server
          - security-server
          - api-gateway         
        expose:
          - "9095"
        ports:
          - "9095:9095"
        networks:
          - microservices          
        restart: "always"
    imovel5:
        image: microservices/imovel:latest
        mem_limit: 1073741824 # RAM 1GB
        environment:
          - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
        depends_on:
          - server
          - security-server
          - api-gateway         
        expose:
          - "9094"
        ports:
          - "9094:9094"
        networks:
          - microservices          
        restart: "always" 
    imovel6:
        image: microservices/imovel:latest
        mem_limit: 1073741824 # RAM 1GB
        environment:
          - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
        depends_on:
          - server
          - security-server
          - api-gateway         
        expose:
          - "9093"
        ports:
          - "9093:9093"
        networks:
          - microservices          
        restart: "always"           
    cliente:
        image: microservices/cliente:latest
        mem_limit: 1073741824 # RAM 1GB
        environment:
          - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
        depends_on:
          - server
          - security-server
          - api-gateway          
        expose:
          - "8083"
        ports:
          - "8083:8083"
        networks:
          - microservices
        restart: "always"            
networks:
  microservices:
    driver: bridge
```

Alguém?

Comment: O docker é uma VM, correto? Não seria o caso de apontar o acesso ao banco para sua máquina na rede, pelo IP? Ou ele não vê nada na rede?

Comment: @Daniel então, ele não vê nada, a menos que seja configurado. Porém, é nessa configuração que não estou conseguindo fazer. Mas é o que você falou, é como se fosse uma VM.

Comment: @CristianoBombazar conseguiu resolver? Usando o `--network="host"` você consegue acessar seu *localhost* tranquilamente e acessar seu banco

Answer (score 2):

Como o seu banco está instalado na sua máquina *host*, você precisa dizer para o container acessar a rede em que sua máquina está, assim ele vai enxergar o seu *host* (o famoso `127.0.0.1`).

Sim, é possível. No momento em que executar o seu container com o `docker run`, você usa o `--network="host"`, assim, o *docker* vai enxergar o endereço local `127.0.0.1`, assim você pode fazer a conexão normalmente com o seu banco.

**obs¹:** Se estiver usando [Docker for Mac](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#there-is-no-docker0-bridge-on-macos#i-want-to-connect-from-a-container-to-a-service-on-the-host) ou [Docker for Windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/networking/#there-is-no-docker0-bridge-on-windows#i-want-to-connect-from-a-container-to-a-service-on-the-host) 18.03+ pode conectar usando o *host* `host.docker.internal`.

**obs²:** Existem outras maneiras (algumas melhores) de se fazer isso, essa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach/24326540#24326540) detalha muito bem outras formas.